# how long does google take to update my meta data?

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console

HI so just a bit explanation my website is still in development when I started google decided to index my website and the resulted in strange weird meta and tiles in google search but I finally got to the SEO part of my website where I added all the meta tags with the correct data etc... now I have submitted my URL to be updated in google webmaster but how long will this take and will this fix the meta display problem in google?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: What is the URL of the website?